# JavaScript alert box with timer

Tags: javascript

I want to display the alert box but for a certain interval. Is it possible in JavaScript?

Comment: Can you clarify? Do you mean you want it to stay visible for a set time, then hide automatically? Or do you want to wait for a bit, then show the alert box?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

If you want an alert to appear after a certain about time, you can use this code:

```
setTimeout(function() { alert("my message"); }, time);
```

If you want an alert to appear and disappear after a specified interval has passed, then you're out of luck.  When an `alert` has fired, the browser stops processing the javascript code until the user clicks "ok".  This happens again when a `confirm` or `prompt` is shown.

If you want the appear/disappear behavior, then I would recommend using something like [jQueryUI's dialog widget](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog).  Here's a quick example on how you might use it to achieve that behavior.

```
var dialog = $(foo).dialog('open');
setTimeout(function() { dialog.dialog('close'); }, time);
```

Comment: But how to you open a simple dialog with a simple text in it?

Answer (score 12):

May be it's too late but the following code works fine

```
document.getElementById('alrt').innerHTML='<b>Please wait, Your download will start soon!!!</b>'; 
setTimeout(function() {document.getElementById('alrt').innerHTML='';},5000);

<div id='alrt' style="fontWeight = 'bold'"></div>
```

Comment: FYI, The "5000" above is in milliseconds.

Answer (score 6):

```
setTimeout( function ( ) { alert( "moo" ); }, 10000 ); //displays msg in 10 seconds
```

Comment: I don't think that'll work.  The code will just display an alert that says "undefined".  This is because when the timeout-callback invoke, no parameters are passed to it.

Comment: What? It works fine. Of course you have to set msg to something.

Comment: BJorn Thanks for the answer. but I want alert box will disappear after interval of time.

Comment: @John alert boxes are browser based modal dialogs and are not removable with JavaScript. You may want to use HTML and create a non-browser based alert. People sometimes refer to this as a dom popup.

Comment: It doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

In short, the answer is no. Once you show an `alert`, `confirm`, or `prompt` the script no longer has control until the user returns control by clicking one of the buttons.

To do what you want, you will want to use DOM elements like a `div` and show, then hide it after a specified time. If you need to be modal (takes over the page, allowing no further action) you will have to do additional work.

You could of course use one of the many "dialog" libraries out there. One that comes to mind right away is the [jQuery UI Dialog widget](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/)

Answer (score 1):

I finished my time alert with a unwanted effect.... Browsers add stuff to windows.  My script is an aptated one and I will show after the following text.

I found a CSS script for popups, which doesn't have unwanted browser stuff. This was written by Prakash:- https://codepen.io/imprakash/pen/GgNMXO.  This script I will show after the following text.

This CSS script above looks professional and is alot more tidy.  This button could be a clickable company logo image.  By suppressing this button/image from running a function, this means you can run this function from inside javascript or call it with CSS, without it being run by clicking it.

This popup alert stays inside the window that popped it up. So if you are a multi-tasker you won't have trouble knowing what alert goes with what window.

The statements above are valid ones.... (Please allow).
How these are achieved will be down to experimentation, as my knowledge of CSS is limited at the moment, but I learn fast.

CSS menus/DHTML use mouseover(valid statement).

I have a CSS menu script of my own which is adapted from 'Javascript for dummies' that pops up a menu alert.  This works, but text size is limited. This hides under the top window banner. This could be set to be timed alert. This isn't great, but I will show this after the following text.

The Prakash script above I feel could be the answer if you can adapt it.

Scripts that follow:- My adapted timed window alert, Prakash's CSS popup script, my timed menu alert.

1.

```
<html>
      <head>
            <title></title>
            <script language="JavaScript">
        // Variables
            leftposition=screen.width-350
            strfiller0='<table border="1" cellspacing="0" width="98%"><tr><td><br>'+'Alert: '+'<br><hr width="98%"><br>'
            strfiller1='&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; This alert is a timed one.'+'<br><br><br></td></tr></table>'
            temp=strfiller0+strfiller1
        // Javascript
            // This code belongs to Stephen Mayes Date: 25/07/2016 time:8:32 am


            function preview(){
                            preWindow= open("", "preWindow","status=no,toolbar=no,menubar=yes,width=350,height=180,left="+leftposition+",top=0");
                            preWindow.document.open();
                            preWindow.document.write(temp);
                            preWindow.document.close();
                    setTimeout(function(){preWindow.close()},4000); 
            }

             </script>
      </head>
<body>
    <input type="button" value=" Open " onclick="preview()">
</body>
</html>
```

2.

```
<style>
body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  background: url(http://www.shukatsu-note.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/computer-564136_1280.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100vh;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #06D85F;
  margin: 80px 0;
}

.box {
  width: 40%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
  padding: 35px;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 20px/50px;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  text-align: center;
}

.button {
  font-size: 1em;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #06D85F;
  border-radius: 20px/50px;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}
.button:hover {
  background: #06D85F;
}

.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  transition: opacity 500ms;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}
.overlay:target {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.popup {
  margin: 70px auto;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 30%;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 5s ease-in-out;
}

.popup h2 {
  margin-top: 0;
  color: #333;
  font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
}
.popup .close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 30px;
  transition: all 200ms;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
}
.popup .close:hover {
  color: #06D85F;
}
.popup .content {
  max-height: 30%;
  overflow: auto;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px){
  .box{
    width: 70%;
  }
  .popup{
    width: 70%;
  }
}
</style>
<script>
    // written by Prakash:- https://codepen.io/imprakash/pen/GgNMXO 
</script>
<body>
<h1>Popup/Modal Windows without JavaScript</h1>
<div class="box">
    <a class="button" href="#popup1">Let me Pop up</a>
</div>

<div id="popup1" class="overlay">
    <div class="popup">
        <h2>Here i am</h2>
        <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
        <div class="content">
            Thank to pop me out of that button, but now i'm done so you can close this window.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

3.

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Using DHTML to Create Sliding Menus (From JavaScript For Dummies, 4th Edition)</TITLE>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript" TYPE="text/javascript">
<!-- Hide from older browsers

function displayMenu(currentPosition,nextPosition) {

    // Get the menu object located at the currentPosition on the screen
    var whichMenu = document.getElementById(currentPosition).style;

    if (displayMenu.arguments.length == 1) {
        // Only one argument was sent in, so we need to
        // figure out the value for "nextPosition"

        if (parseInt(whichMenu.top) == -5) {
            // Only two values are possible: one for mouseover
            // (-5) and one for mouseout (-90). So we want
            // to toggle from the existing position to the
            // other position: i.e., if the position is -5,
            // set nextPosition to -90...
            nextPosition = -90;
        }
        else {
            // Otherwise, set nextPosition to -5
            nextPosition = -5;
        }
    }

    // Redisplay the menu using the value of "nextPosition"
    whichMenu.top = nextPosition + "px";
}

// End hiding-->
</SCRIPT>

<STYLE TYPE="text/css">
<!--

.menu {position:absolute; font:10px arial, helvetica, sans-serif; background-color:#ffffcc; layer-background-color:#ffffcc; top:-90px}
#resMenu {right:10px; width:-130px}
A {text-decoration:none; color:#000000}
A:hover {background-color:pink; color:blue}

 -->

</STYLE>

</HEAD>

<BODY BGCOLOR="white">

<div id="resMenu" class="menu" onmouseover="displayMenu('resMenu',-5)" onmouseout="displayMenu('resMenu',-90)"><br />
<a href="#"> Alert:</a><br>
<a href="#"> </a><br>
<a href="#"> You pushed that button again... Didn't yeah? </a><br>
<a href="#"> </a><br>
<a href="#"> </a><br>
<a href="#"> </a><br>
</div>
ddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd
<input type="button" value="Wake that alert up" onclick="displayMenu('resMenu',-5)">
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 1):

Pure **HTML + CSS** 5 seconds alert box using the `details` element toggling.

```css
details > p {
  padding: 1rem;
  margin: 0
}

details[open] {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  width: 33%;
  transform: translate(calc(50vw - 50%), calc(50vh - 50%));
  transform-origin: center center;
  outline: 10000px #000000d4 solid;
  animation: alertBox 5s;
  border: 15px yellow solid
}

details[open] summary::after {
  content: '❌';
  float: right
}

@keyframes alertBox {
  0%   { visibility: unset}
  100% { visibility: hidden }
}
```

```html
<details>
  <summary>Show the box 5s</summary>
  <p>HTML and CSS popup with 5s tempo.</p>
  <p><b>Powered by HTML</b></p>
</details>
```

Nb: the visibility stay hidden at closure, haven't found a way to restore it from CSS, we might have to use js to toggle a class to show it again. If someone find a way with only CSS, please edit this post!!

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for an alert that dissapears after an interval you could try the jQuery UI Dialog widget.

Answer (score 0):

tooltips can be used as alerts.  These can be timed to appear and disappear.

CSS can be used to create tooltips and menus.  More info on this can be found in 'Javascript for Dummies'.  Sorry about the label of this book...  Not infuring anything.

Reading other peoples answers here, I realized the answer to my own thoughts/questions.  SetTimeOut could be applied to tooltips.  Javascript could trigger them.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people would benefit greatly from a few examples, of the methods you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

by using this code you can set the timer on the alert box , and it will pop up after 10 seconds.

```
setTimeout(function(){
         alert("after 10 sec i will start");
         },10000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can now use the [HTMLDialogElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLDialogElement).

In this example a dialog is created when you click the button, and a timeout function is created to close it:

```js
async function showMessage(message) {
  const dialog = document.createElement("dialog");
  document.body.appendChild(dialog);
  dialog.innerText = message;
  dialog.show();
  setTimeout(function () {
    dialog.close();
  }, 1000);
}
```

```html
<button class="btn" onclick="showMessage('This is my message')">click me!</button>
```

If you want you can test it on [codepen](https://codepen.io/pjbelo/pen/abjKEGz).

Answer (score 0):

```
function alertWithTimeout(title,message,timeout){
    var dialog = $("<div id='dialog-confirm' title='"+title+"'>"+message+"</div>").dialog(); 
    setTimeout(function() { dialog.dialog('close'); }, timeout);
}
alertWithTimeout("Error","This is the message" ,5000);
```