# confirm alert window in phantom.js

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, phantomjs, confirm

i have this function which find button and click it, but after that alert appears and i need to confirm it using phantom.js

```
function() {
  page.evaluate(function() {
    $('.item-list clicked').first().find($('.comment-delete')).find('a').click();
  })
}
```

may be i can emulate function which call alert whithout click immediately ? or use function waitFor for waiting this alert?(unlikely this, waitFor waiting only for DOM objects i think so)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, Phantom.JS is headless.
The only thing you can do is get the context of the alert with

```
window.onAlert = function(alertText){
    ...
   }
```

but no more than this I think.
You cannot either close (in general) or render (in Phantom.JS) the alert programmatically.

Some sources:
* [Render JavaScript alerts with Phantom.JS](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/phantomjs/w_rKkFJ0g8w)
* [Close alert programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1962878/2964675)

Comment: oh, it's sad, but thank you for answer. may be you know other tools which able to confirm alerts ?)

Comment: You can use Zombie.js (see [here](http://zombie.labnotes.org/API#browser-onalert-fn) ). Have a look also to SlimerJS: it might have the `window.alert`...

Answer (score 6):

I can't find the other stackoverflow answer that helped me answer this as well but basically you can inject a javascript function that will confirm the alert popup:

Here's my python webdriver implementation:

```
def example_js_confirmation( self ):
    js_confirm = 'window.confirm = function(){return true;}'    # .js function to confirm a popup
    self.execute_javascript( js_confirm )
    self.find_by_id( 'submit' ).click()
    self.execute_javascript( 'return window.confirm' )  # trigger the injected js that returns true (virtually click OK)
```

It's on somebody's todo list =) :
[Selenium Desired Capabilities - set handlesAlerts for PhantomJS driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16022226/selenium-desired-capabilities-set-handlesalerts-for-phantomjs-driver)

Answer (score 0):

"Confirm an alert" is a confusing phrase, because Javascript provides both `alert` (which shows a message with an OK button) and `confirm` (which shows OK and Cancel buttons), and it's not clear which one you mean.

At least PhantomJS 2.x behaves as if it clicks OK on `alert` boxes and Cancel on `confirm` boxes.

If you want to click OK instead of Cancel on `confirm` boxes, you could call `execute_javascript` to override `window.confirm` to return `true` as long as you're not worried about `confirm` boxes that pop up *during the load process* which will be dealt with before your `execute_javascript` has a chance to intervene.  If you want to catch those as well, the best thing I can think of is to patch PhantomJS source or inject the JS via an upstream proxy.

Answer (score -1):

I did that:

```
// 1) override window.alert
page.evaluate(function(){
  window.alert = function(msg){
    window.callPhantom({alert: msg}); // will call page.onCallback()
    return true; // will "close the alert"
  };
});

// 2) re-bind to onAlert()
page.onCallback = function(obj) {
  page.onAlert(obj.alert); // will trigger page.onAlert()
};
```