# jQueryUI modal dialog and delay close

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

I'm using contact form in modal jQueryUI dialog, I would like to show an string "your mail was sent successfully" for 1.5 seconds and then close an dialog. I use that code for it:

```
$( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        "Cancel": function() {
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        },
        "Send": function() {
            $( this ).dialog( "option", "hide", { delay: 1500 } );
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
          }
        }
      },
      close: function() {
      }
});
```

(removed some code for more clarity)

Code generally works, dialog window closes after 1.5 second of delay as I expect.

but, opacity which covers rest of site "under" dialog disappear without timeout.

Comment: i think this is what your looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1962861/javascript-alert-box-with-timer

Comment: Thank you! I tried it before but used setTimeout(function() { $( this ).dialog('close'); }, 1500) which is wrong, now I put $( "#dialog-form" ) instead of $( this ) and it works. Thanks again!