# How to redirect the page while an alert() box is open and NOT CLICKED on "OK" for a certain time

Tags: javascript, redirect, dialog, settimeout, alert

A alert() box is opened when I click on a button. An alert has only 'OK' as an input. 
1. I want to redirect if the person doesn't click on 'OK' for a certain time (2seconds)
2. Is there a better popup where the user doesn't have to click on anything, where it just shows the message and just redirects. Something other than (prompt,alert,confirm)

I also want to redirect to the same page if he clicks on 'OK', which I have already done.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.btn').click(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    var popup = alert("Thank you");

    if (!popup) {
      window.location.href = "www.google.com";
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn" style="background: #FF3900; color: #fff;">
</form>
```

Need to redirect if no action is taken after pop up is displayed. My page doesn't do anything, after the button is clicked and the pop up is shown. If i change tabs, it automatically for some reason redirects to the asked site.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript alert box with timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1962861/javascript-alert-box-with-timer)

Answer (score 1):

The alert is blocking the further code execution as already mentioned. One workaround would be to create custom popup, and start a timer once it is opened. Then if button is not clicked inside the popup, redirect, if it is clicked, abord the timeout. For example:

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
      var $activeTimer; // global timer to track inactivity

      $('.btn').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#popup').addClass('active'); // show the popup on click
        
        // start the timer
        $activeTimer = setTimeout(function(){
            // do something after certain seconds of inactivity
            window.location.href = "www.google.com";
        }, 3500)
      });
      
      // if ok button in popup is clicked, abort the timer for example
      $('#confirm').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        clearTimeout($activeTimer);
        // do something when clicked
      })
    });
```

```css
#popup {
   position: fixed;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   opacity: 0;
   z-index: -1;
   padding: 2em 3em;
   border: 1px solid #333;
}

#popup.active {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 9999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn" style="background: #FF3900; color: #fff;">
      <div id="popup">
        <p>Thank you<p>
        <a href="" id="confirm">Ok</a>
      </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: the thank you is shown on the html page itself, and not as a pop up. The popup also does not appear

Answer (score 0):

`alert()` is blocking javascript's execution.

```
alert('alert')
console.log('log')
```

'log' would not appear in console until you close the alert dialog.

So only way to solve your problem is to create custom dialog window without using built-in `alert`